# linux error flag in permission denied thing

Tags: files, file-copy, profile

Even after running the command `sudo chmod -R 777 /home`, I cannot fix the error:

> Sorry, user kumarht1 is not allowed to execute '/bin/chmod -R 777 /kumarht1' as root on host.com.

How should I fix this problem?

Comment: Please explain how changing `/home` to 777 would affect `/kumarth1`, it is not as if you are trying `/home/kumarth1` or possible `~/kumarth1`

Comment: Doing such a (recursive!) `chmod(1)` is an extremely bad idea. Fixing the permissions mess you just created will take a lot of work. Congratulations, as the saying goes, "Unix provides more than enough rope to shoot off your feet".

Answer (score 1):

This error is simply telling you that you do not have permissions to run `sudo` commands, not that there is a permissions error with the `/bin/chmod` file or anything within your home directory. You will need to speak to your systems administrator to gain `sudo` permissions; if you are the systems administrator, use `su -` to gain root access with the root password, and then use `visudo` to grant your regular user `sudo` permissions. You can, of course, simply `chmod` your home directory as your regular user, this operation does not require root permissions, but it would be against `/home/kumarht1`, not against `/home`.

Comment: The OP doesn't have a problem with running `sudo` that is clear from his post. The problem is trying to change a directory, not under `/home` but directly under `/` without using `sudo`

Comment: The only problem evident in the OP's post is that he doesn't have permission to use `sudo`.

Comment: The OP writes he has run sudo, he doesn't indicate that threw an error, the next command, **without** sudo throws an error and that is to be expected.

Comment: No, the OP writes that sudo is throwing an error that "user kumarht1 is not allowed to execute '/bin/chmod -R 777 /kumarht1' as root on host.com" There is no evidence of any other command being run with or without sudo.